# can golang function return interface{}{} - how to return a map list

Tags: go, interface, go-map

```
func getLatestTxs() map[string]interface{}{} {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    resp, err := http.Get("http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x266ac31358d773af8278f625c4d4a35648953341&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=5UUVIZV5581ENPXKYWAUDGQTHI956A56MU")
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("etherscan访问失败")
    }
    ret := map[string]interface{}{}
    json.Unmarshal(body, &ret)
    if ret["status"] == 1 {
        return ret["result"]
    }
}
```

I want return `map[string]interface{}{}` in my code.

but i got compile error `syntax error: unexpected [ after top level declaration`

if i change `map[string]interface{}{}` to `interface{}`, there is no compile error any more.

**Attention** i use `map[string]interface{}{}` because i want return a map list.

Comment: for a map list use `[]` in front. e.g. `[]map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: @mkopriva if we use `[]map[string]interface{}` it will throw an error. Since `ret["result"]` is an `interface{}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code `map[string]interface{}{}` is a composite literal value for an empty map. Functions are declared with types, not values. It looks like you want to return the slice type `[]map[string]interface{}`.  Use the following function:

```
func getLatestTxs() []map[string]interface{} {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    resp, err := http.Get("http://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0x266ac31358d773af8278f625c4d4a35648953341&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=5UUVIZV5581ENPXKYWAUDGQTHI956A56MU")
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("etherscan访问失败")
    }
    var ret struct {
        Status  string
        Result  []map[string]interface{}
    }
    json.Unmarshal(body, &ret)
    if ret.Status == "1" {
        return ret.Result
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: i want return a map list, `ret["result"]`, looks you are return a map, That`s right?

Answer (score 1):

Create return type to `map[string]interface{}`. Because the response returned from `GET` request is of type `map[string]interface{}` not `map[string]interface{}{}` which is a composite literal. So you can use it like

```
func getLatestTxs() map[string]interface{} {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    // function body code ....
    return ret
}
```

For this line

> if i change map[string]interface{}{} to interface{}, there is no
>   compile error any more.

We can convert anything to `interface{}` because it works as a wrapper which can wrap any type and will save the underlying type and its value. The value can be received using type assertion for an underlying type. So in your case when you are using an interface it will wrap `map[string]interface{}` value. For fetching the value it is required to type assert as below.

```
func getLatestTxs() interface{} {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    // function code .....
    //fmt.Println(ret["result"])
    return ret
}


ret["result"].(interface{}).([]interface{})
```

print the underlying `map[string]interface{}` to get the value of single object inside result

```
fmt.Println(ret["result"].(interface{}).([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["from"])
```

Comment: `fmt.Println(ret["result"].(interface{}).([]interface{}))` in your case ret["result"] is actually an `interface{}` not `map[string]interface{}` and its innner value is `[]interface{}` slice of interface